# Android - changing layout view on selected custom list item

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I have a customised list view adapter and 2 layout xml files one for standard view and one that I would like to appear when a list item is selected

I want it to work so that if I select an item in the list more data is displayed and if I select another item the previously selected item goes back to the default, as in only one item can be selected at any give time.

heres what I have tried, but it doesn't work as I want, any suggestions ??

**MainActivity.java File**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
ListView lv;
List<ListViewItem> items;
CustomListViewAdapter adapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    items  = new ArrayList<MainActivity.ListViewItem>();
    items.add(new ListViewItem()
    {{
        ThumbnailResource = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
        Title = "Item1";
        SubTitle = "Item1 Description";
        Detail1 =" more details";
        Detail2 ="01 123455";
    }});
    items.add(new ListViewItem()
    {{
        ThumbnailResource = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
        Title = "Item2";
        SubTitle = "Item2 Description";
        Detail1 ="additional  details";
        Detail2 ="090 641123";
    }});

    adapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(this, items);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

              adapter.selectedItem(position);
              adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

class ListViewItem
{
    public int ThumbnailResource;
    public String Title;
    public String SubTitle;
    public String Detail1;
    public String Detail2;
}
```

}

**CustomListViewAdapter.java**

```
package com.customlistview;

import java.util.List;

import com.customlistview.MainActivity.ListViewItem;

import android.app.Activity;  
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;  
import android.view.View;  
import android.view.ViewGroup;  
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;  
import android.widget.ImageView;  
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;  
import android.widget.Toast;

public class CustomListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{  

LayoutInflater inflater;
List<ListViewItem> items;
int position;

public CustomListViewAdapter(Activity context, List<ListViewItem> items) {  
    super();

    this.items = items;
    this.inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override  
public int getCount() {  
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
    return items.size();  
}  

@Override  
public Object getItem(int position) {  
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
    return null;  
}  

@Override  
public long getItemId(int position) {  
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
    return 0;  
}
public void selectedItem(int position)
{
   this.position = position; //position must be a global variable
}
@Override  
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {  
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub  


    ListViewItem item = items.get(position);

    View vi=convertView;
    View vi2=convertView;


    if(convertView==null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_row, null);


    ImageView imgView = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.imgThumbnail);
    TextView txtTitle = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
    TextView txtSubTitle = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.txtSubTitle);

    imgView.setImageResource(item.ThumbnailResource);
    txtTitle.setText(item.Title);
    txtSubTitle.setText(item.SubTitle);

    if(this.position == position)
    {
        vi2 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_row_selected, null);
        ImageView imgView2 = (ImageView) vi2.findViewById(R.id.imgThumbnail);
        TextView txtTitle2 = (TextView) vi2.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
        TextView txtSubTitle2 = (TextView) vi2.findViewById(R.id.txtSubTitle);

        imgView2.setImageResource(item.ThumbnailResource);
        txtTitle2.setText(item.Title);
        txtSubTitle2.setText(item.SubTitle);

        return vi2;
    }
             return vi;  
}



}
```

Selected Xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout   
android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"   
android:layout_width="fill_parent"   
android:layout_height="fill_parent"   
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
android:padding="5dip">  

<ImageView   
    android:layout_width="78dip"   
    android:layout_height="78dip"   
    android:id="@+id/imgThumbnail"   
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"  
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="-3dip"
    android:scaleType="centerInside">  
</ImageView>  

<TextView   
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"   
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
    android:text="TextView"   
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"   
    android:id="@+id/txtTitle"   
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgThumbnail"
    android:layout_marginTop="6dip"  
    android:layout_marginLeft="6dip">  
</TextView>  

<TextView   
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
    android:text="TextView"   
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"   
    android:id="@+id/txtSubTitle"   
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgThumbnail"  
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtTitle"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dip"  
    android:layout_marginLeft="6dip">  
</TextView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtdet1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/txtSubTitle"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txtSubTitle"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txtTitle"
    android:text="TextView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtdet2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txtSubTitle"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/TextView01"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtSubTitle"
    android:text="TextView" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnaccept"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imgThumbnail"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtdet2"
    android:text="details" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btndetails"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txtdet2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtdet2"
    android:text="cancel" />
```

**Standard layout xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<RelativeLayout   
android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"   
android:layout_width="fill_parent"   
android:layout_height="fill_parent"   
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
android:padding="5dip">  

<ImageView   
    android:layout_width="78dip"   
    android:layout_height="78dip"   
    android:id="@+id/imgThumbnail"   
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"  
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="-3dip"
    android:scaleType="centerInside">  
</ImageView>  

<TextView   
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"   
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
    android:text="TextView"   
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"   
    android:id="@+id/txtTitle"   
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgThumbnail"
    android:layout_marginTop="6dip"  
    android:layout_marginLeft="6dip">  
</TextView>  

<TextView   
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
    android:text="TextView"   
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"   
    android:id="@+id/txtSubTitle"   
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgThumbnail"  
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtTitle"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dip"  
    android:layout_marginLeft="6dip">  
</TextView>
```

Comment: Why don't you merge both the layouts and simply hide/unhide the extra information on selection of the item?

Comment: You could combine both your views in one layout file and maybe toggle visibility in onItemClick

Comment: I want to have as many items displaying on the list as possible so want to increase the height of the row on click and then display the additional info. hiding and unhiding the information would work if I could set the height programmatically, but I cant seem to set the height in the GetView as getLayoutParams returns a null. Also how can I reset the height of any previously clicked rows.

Answer (score 0):

I did as simar suggested and added a flag to the listviewItem to toggle visibility , I then toggled this flag on click of the item for the controls I want to show or hide

```
txtdet1.setVisibility( item.Expanded ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
```